# Deny full node access for anonymous users

Tags: users

I know it's possible to deny access for the whole node, but I need it only for the full view, so anonymous users can see the teaser; when they access the node, they will get a 403 error. Is it possible?

I've tried premium content modules, but this is not what I want.